# C++ high_resolution_clock::now() showing inconsistent results with wallclock time

Tags: c++, c++11, c++-chrono

I was trying to calculate the time required to sample 7680 bit primes in FLINT library. I had a loop running for 100 iterations and finally calculated the average time required. On my mac, the below code took more than 5 hours to run (I left the code running in mac at 2:00clock without closing the lid. When I saw again at 7:00clock, the code is still running). But finally, it showed an output of "33.3442" seconds. How is this possible?

```
#include "fmpz.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
using namespace std;
using namespace std::chrono;

int main() {  
    int count = 100;
    int length = 7680;

    fmpz_t primes[count];   
    flint_rand_t state;
    flint_randinit(state);

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        fmpz_init(primes[i]);


    auto start = high_resolution_clock::now(); 
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        while (true)
        {
             fmpz_randbits(primes[i], state, length);
             if (fmpz_is_probabprime(primes[i]))
                  break;
        }
    }
    auto stop = high_resolution_clock::now(); 
    auto duration = duration_cast<microseconds>(stop - start); 
    cout << "Generating random primes of length " << length << " " << ((double)duration.count()/1000000)/count << endl; 
}
```

Comment: (For the record: The code displays time per outer loop iteration. Total runtime would therefore be 100 * 33 seconds = ~1 hour).

Comment: I don't know flint library. Is it possible it use lazy evaluation ? Can you print all the prime you get before your stop timer ?

Comment: Yes, we can print the primes[i] using flint_printf() function. But how does that help?

Comment: For timing long functions, `system_clock` can be more reliable.  But if your computer goes to sleep during the timing event, it won't really matter which clock you use.

Comment: @HowardHinnant I am just curious on what happens if the computer goes to sleep (but the lid is open). Will the code keep running but the timer does not run? If that is the case, that might justify my problem?

Comment: The C++ standard has nothing to say here.  It will vary with the OS.  Your best bet is to run some controlled experiments.

Comment: @satya Most likely neither code nor timer was running. But this is nothing we can reliably diagnose with the info given here.

Comment: @MaxLanghof My lid is open, but my display went off. Assuming my laptop is at sleep and timer is off. I can probably trust the results I got. My laptop would have actually run the code for only 1 hour and that's consistent with the output.